# Which "address" should be used when wallet is made with iancoleman page?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed, bip

If I have generated / choosen the 12 word memnonic with bip39 here

https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

which address I should fill in Binance as the destination address when withdrowing coins?

- Account Extended Public Key or
- BIP32 Extended Public Key or
- choose one of the Derived Addresses from the table?

[image]

If option 1 or 2 is used, is it possible that tranfer will "override" one of the previous address, or it "checks" always wether new "sub" address is empty?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the first of the "Derived Addresses" that you have not previously used.

However, first of all I would test recovery from a written copy of the "BIP39 mnemonic" using an offline non-custodial wallet (e.g. Electrum etc) and check that it can generate the same address.